# How to buy Legendary Pictographs from Lenzo?

Tags: zelda-wind-waker

So Lenzo will not give me the dialogue option to buy any Legendary Pictographs, no matter what phase the moon is in.

I have already beaten the game, and am playing on the Second Quest profile (the one where you start out with the Deluxe Pictobox). In my first profile, he offers them to me fine when I talk to him at night. When I talk to him on my second profile, however, he just says something about me being his assistant. He gives me a different dialogue option when I show a pictograph to him, but nothing about buying Legendaries from him.

**EDIT:** I tried even doing the Pictobox quests for the people around Windfall on my second profile, but still no change. Also, I am playing the Wind Waker HD.

Comment: Figurines carry over from your first game, so do you still need the legendary pictographs? That might be why he's not offering them.

Comment: Yes, I do. I only got about 2 Legendaries in the first game. And like I said, if I try going back and buying them in my first profile he still will.

Comment: I think you also must have encountered the legendary character in the story before Lenzo will offer their pictograph. Have you done that? How far are you in second quest? Also, if he's offering them in your first profile, why not just get them there, make figurines, and then start a second quest?

Comment: I'm near the end of the game in the Second Quest (after you beat the Forsaken Fortress for a second time), so that's why I can't start the second quest now. And I think the Second Quest profile starts only automatically by the game when you beat the game on your first profile. 

I'll try and see if maybe I haven't encountered the characters I can't buy.

Comment: Ah ha! It was that you have to encounter the character before he offers them. I went and viewed the Queen of Faries and did the Earth and Wind Temple and he offered all of them! Thanks, I finally fully completed the Nintendo Gallery!

Comment: Hey, glad it worked. In that case, I'll make an answer out of my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the requirements is that you must have encountered the character in the story before Lenzo will offer their pictograph. After that, you should be able to buy them like normal.

Answer (score 0):

[According to ZeldaWiki](http://zeldawiki.org/Pictograph), you have to have completed the Forsaken Fortress to buy Legendary Pictographs.

Comment: I have already beaten the Forsaken Fortress (first and second times) on both accounts.

Answer (score 0):

After you have the deluxe pictobox you need to complete every pictobox side quest on windfall to unlock the legendary photo (lady in front of potion shop, full moon dude on the stairs, gossip ladies)

Comment: Hi, are these the names of the quests you need to finish? "(lady in front of potion shop, full moon dude on the stairs, gossip ladies)" Are there only three?